# Magnetic sensor and image rotation in Android

Tags: java, android

trying to build an magnetic compass, I have the following code.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    imageCompass = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageMapDrawView);
    Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.compass);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(event.values[0] );
    Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight(),
            matrix, true);
    imageCompass.setImageBitmap(rotated);
}
```

I have the following questions,
A. I guess event.values[0] is in degree? not in radian?
B. I want to get the image from image view  and rotate it around the center of the image, where I am telling that?
C. I want to draw another image (an indicator on top of that Image), can I do this? I have already an compass image in the image view  and I want to draw another image on top. I can't redraw whole view. How can I achieve it?

Comment: a) check it out by yourself, b) use setImageMatrix, be sure scaleType is "matrix": c) use LayerDrawable

Comment: setImageMatrix does not rotate the image at all, setImageBitmap rotate the image but around wrong center, any idea here?

Comment: setImageMatrix works as expected but it needs scale type set to matrix

Comment: I used the following code for  LayerDrawable                                               Resources r = getResources();
        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
        layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.compass);
        layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.travelarrow);
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
        imageGPSMapDrawView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable); problem here is that  layers[1] is enlarged as layers[0] and that I don't expect. Also I want to rotate the arrow around the center of layers[0], how can I achieve this?

Comment: layers[1] is a BitmapDrawable so you can setGravity on that, if you want to rotate use RotateDrawable

Comment: Looks wasting time, can you show me some code? I want to rotate a dial (like speedometer) on compass when I get angle from the sensor. I don't want to rotate the compass itself but I like to rotate the dial around the  center of compass image.

Comment: what kind of problem did you find? post the code you wrote so far

Comment: Resources r = getResources();
        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
        layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.compass);
        layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.travelarrow);
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
        imageGPSMapDrawView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
        Bitmap anArrowImage      = ((BitmapDrawable) layers[1]).getBitmap();
        BitmapDrawable dd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),anArrowImage);
//        dd.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);  tried with 1, 2, etc, no idea what would be right value

Answer (score 0):

A. Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html.

The length and contents of the values array depends on which sensor type is being monitored.

```
Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER is in m/s²
Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD is in uT (micro Tesla)
Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE is in rad/s
```

and go on for all sensors (check the link).

Also, interface SensorListener is Deprecated since API level 3. You should use  SensorEventListener instead.

B and C. You should consider using OpenGL ES for drawing your images. Specially OpenGL ES 2.0 gives you so much details and ways manipulate your images that would be easy to do let you do about anything you need.